# Running leaks command line tool on an app on device

Tags: ios, macos, memory-leaks, instruments

I am able to run leaks instruments on an app that I run on a device using XCode.

What I want to do is use the leaks command line tool (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/leaks.1.html) , to run leaks on an app that runs on the simulator.

Has someone already done that? And if yes can someone tell me how to do it?

(PID for the app running on simulator is not available on my mac)

Comment: You can see the PID of apps running in the simulator in Activity Monitor for instance. You can also use the Leaks module in Instruments.

Comment: The app is not running on simulator. I need the PID of an app that runs on a real device. I have constraints because of which I can only use the leaks command line tool, though instruments is a very good choice.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, unless you run the `leaks` command *on* the device, for which you need to jailbreak it.

Answer (score -2):

You can not use the command line version without knowing the PID.
The command line version needs a PID.

The PID is in activity monitor though.

I would personally suggest using the GUI, as it is much easier though.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingLeaks.html

Comment: He was trying to use it on an iOS device, not on a OSX application. So of course he can't look up for the PID on the activity monitor.